# Can I use rimless tape with an inner tube on a regular (tube style) rim?

Tags: road-bike, innertube, puncture, tubeless, rim-tape

The plastic and cloth rim tapes at my LBS come in a couple of sizes: too narrow and too wide. Too narrow barely covers the spoke holes (meaning, it doesn't). Too wide gets into the bead area, making it (slightly) more difficult to mount a tire, and worse, it catches on the tire when I mount or dismount it, and when I check the mount to make sure I haven't pinched the tube. Both plastic and cloth tapes move laterally, potentially exposing spoke holes. Aamof, the cloth rim tape I installed a couple of rides ago has already shifted a little. Once off center, both cloth and plastic tapes take a set, making them tend to stay off center.

Tubeless tapes have an actual adhesive backing, as opposed to the tacky stuff on cloth tapes, and nothing at all on the plastic ones. The adhesive should keep the tape from moving (right?). Some tubeless tapes are also very thin, so are unlikely to be pushed off center by the tire during mounting/dismounting. Obviously thin tubeless tape can take the pressure, but I don't know if will adequately protect a tube. Has anyone tried using tubeless tape with a tube on a tube type rim? How about *thin* tubeless tape?

For what it's worth, I ride 700 mm x 25 mm road tires, 100 to 110 psi. I don't get many flats due to rim tape failure--I check the tape when I repair a flat (which I do way too often).

I have another rim tape question. I'll post it separately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an interesting thought - I'd expect tubeless tape to be a lot more expensive.   Can you add the widths of rim tape you have access to?   15mm and 19mm would be common sizes.

Comment: You could conceivably put some double sided tape between your normal rimtape and the rim itself, to help prevent creeping.

Comment: I don't really know how smart it is to run road pressures with tubes on tubeless tape for long periods. It won't fail in the short term but it wouldn't surprise me if it had durability issues sooner than conventional tape. However it should be noted that in other applications, tubes on tubeless tape is 100% fine. Most nicer mountain bikes have been coming that way for years now.

Comment: I keep tape and the such on hand. The cloth tape package I'm looking at comes in widths of 11 mm, 17 mm, and 22 mm. I had a roll of 11 mm and a few rolls of 17. I tried the 11 mm first: too narrow. The 17 mm works, but it comes up the sides of the valley and gets pushed around by the tire bead. The rolls of plastic tape I have in my supply box are 18 mm. I replaced the original plastic tape, (about 19 mm), a couple of rides ago. It was deformed and wouldn't stay centered.

Comment: True, tubeless tape is more expensive, but not terrible. A couple of rolls of cloth or plastic tape is probablye a couple bucks on Amazon, maybe six bucks at the LBS. A 10 yard roll, enough for 4 rims, of tubeless rim tape is around $12 on Amazon. Let's call it $6/rim, since I'm only thinking about one bike at the moment. By comparison, tubes costs around $8 (less on Amazon). Not having to deal with a flat on the side is worth a few bucks, too. I'm not a big spender, but I'm willing to part with the twelve bucks if it will save me a flat some day.

Comment: Interesting idea about double sided tape. Do you suppose it would stick well to the cloth tape? Maybe plastic tape instead, but stretching the plastic tape over the double sided tape might be a challenge. I'll let you know how it goes if I try it. I've also thought about bonding it on with contact cement, etc.

Comment: @NathanKnutson I've read that one of the advantages of tubeless rims is that you *can* run lower pressure, but I didn't know it was required. Rolling resistance increases with decreasing tire pressure. At least that's the case on very smooth roads, aka rolling resistance measurement equipment. On real roads? Hmm. Either way, I've gradually dropped my tire pressures over the years, hoping to reduce the number of flats I get (I rarely get pinch flats). I'm currently running 100 psi front and back, although on occasion I go with 110 psi in the rear. Is that high for tubeless rims?

Comment: BTW, I'm in a league by myself wrt flats. Maybe I'll start a separate discussion on that. Tires and tubes are my biggest riding expense, possibly including the cost of my carbon frame Fuji Transonic. I buy patches in 100 count boxes, contact cement in 3 oz bottles. If you are wondering, patch failure flats are rare for me; I had a tube last year with 8 patches, likely a PR--I'm not really sure. None of the patches leaked; the tube finally failed with a six inch split, not along a seam, and not intersecting any of the patches. I miss that tube! ;^J

Comment: Well you can always use electrician tape to seal the nipple holes on a rim.

Comment: Go buy some hockey tape -- used to wrap hockey sticks.  It may be too wide, but is easily ripped down to the required width.

Comment: Electrical tape is very elastic. My expectation is that it would deform into the holes until either it or the tube eruptures, or is cut on the edge of a spoke hole. The adhesive also turns to goo; I wouldn't expect it to stay put. Anyone tried using electrical tape as rim tape?

Comment: @DanielRHicks I've seen that suggestion before. I might try it. I've also seen duck tape suggested. Hockey is a cold weather sport. I'm in Austin, TX. It gets a bit warm on occasion. ;^J Duck tape adhesive turns to goo when it gets hot (why would anyone use that on ducts? Lol!). Is hockey tape different?

Comment: @riderBill - As with all such tapes there's a significant variation in quality between brands, but hockey tape has less variation than duct tape.  ("Duct tape" has a rather inglorious etymology -- it was, as you suggest, originally "duck tape", but the "duck" referred to the cloth from which it was (once) made, not its (poor) ability to seal ducts.  Rather, it was used by the military to seal metal ammo boxes.  But the name changed to "duct tape" anyway.  And then a company trademarked "Duck Tape" as a brand of the stuff, to add further confusion.)

Comment: (Anyway, hockey tape is better than most duct/duck tape in this service.  Of course, cloth electrical tape can also be used.)

Comment: One advantage of hockey tape is that it's quite thin, and less likely to create interference problems.

Comment: Yeah, duck tape isn't for ducts. Neither is duct tape. Lol! Like I said, I might give hockey tape a try. Other than the local pro team (the Ice Bats. Ever heard of them? A lot of folks around here haven't), there isn't much hockey in Austin; I'd have to get it on Amazon (which I'd do anyway). Care to suggest a brand? Is it anything like the tape you wrap tennis racquet handles with?

Comment: BTW, this isn't an urgent issue for me. I rented a bike when I was out of town a while back. I had a flat (of course. Several, in fact). Turned out, it was a tubeless rim. When I saw the tape, it looked fantastic! I didn't test the adhesive, but it looked strong, and it was perfectly placed, rim wall to rim wall, not climbing up either side. It was translucent orange, and thin as cellophane packing tape, so essentially no interference, even though it extended under the tire bead. It looked good, got me wondering about using it the next time I replaced my tape.

Comment: I asked a related question. [This answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/54403/25234), which I accepted, corrects my assumption about the proper width of rim tape: it should extend wall to wall, covering both the valley and the "flats" beneath the bead hook.

Comment: Standard electrical tape is too stretchy. It will deform into the spoke holes and eventually after a few days your tube will spontaneously go pssssssssssssssuuuhhhhhh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Tubeless tape will support using a tube just fine. Tubeless tape does not stretch (much) so the indentation at the spoke holes is very minor.  Remember it is holding back the same force per square inch as regular rim tape, if it gave way the edge of the spoke holes would cut the tape and the tubeless tape wouldn’t be doing its primary job of retaining air. Finally, while the adhesive does a great job of keeping tubeless tape in place, it can still shift  if extreme lateral force is put on the tape (e.g., a very tight tire + tube+ rim combo)

Comment: Btw Gorilla tape makes a great custom rim tape. It can even be used for tubeless setups.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I knew the tape had to be strong enough to take the pressure, just like "ordinary" rim tapes do. It would be useless, otherwise. I was worried that tubeless tapes might stretch (substantially) into the spoke holes when the tire is pressurized, That wouldn't be a problem for the tape; it just has to seal the rim. But the deformation could allow a tube to stretch too much locally, or, especially with the thin tubeless tapes, be cut on the edge of a spoke hole.

Comment: @riderBill tubeless tape is gives very little, so no worries there.